# azure group sconfigurations in virtual machines

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

I am creating a virtual machine in azure, the virtual machine must belong to the same group of the database? And if not, would it affect its use? Because the group in my database is in a "central us" locality group and I could observe that when placing a new group with "south central us" locality the prices of the virtual machines went down

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to know the daily total of how much the azure server is consuming? I have a membership of 100 dollars and the strange thing is that it ran out very fast

Comment: yes, you could. You had better ask a new question. I would give a new answer to you.

Comment: You could check your cost on Azure Portal. Subscriptions-->Your subscriptions-->Cost analysis

Comment: based on my experience, you had better check whether you use S series VMs. SSD disk is charged different from HDD disk.

Answer (score 2):

`the virtual machine must belong to the same group of the database?`

**No, you could create them in different groups and different data centers.**

However, if you want to your VMs and database communicate with private IP, you need to create a Site-To-Site VPN tunnel. You need pay the cost of the VPN Gateway.More information about Gateway price please refer to the [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/vpn-gateway/).

An Azure SQL database in the same region will not have any additional data transfer costs. [But Outbound data transfer is charged at the normal rate](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/bandwidth/) between two regions.

Based on my knowledge, if your VMs and database are in the same Vnet , it  will have better performance.